# JqGrid searchoptions with select2 existing value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, jquery-select2-4

I'm trying to integrate select2 for JqGrid filter form. I'm using JqGrid min 4.6 & Select2 min 4.0.1. The filter works fine but I'm unable to retrieve the value that has been set through select2 once the filter form is closed and reopened. i.e. dataInit e1 does not return the existing value of the select input. I must be doing something wrong?

JqGrid Column Model:

```
        {
            name: 'CurrencyID', hidden: true, search: true, stype: 'select', searchtype: 'number', searchoptions: {
                searchhidden: true,
                sopt: ['eq', 'ne'],
                dataInit: function (el) {
                    intiGridFilterSelecr2Field(el, paramFromView.CurrencyOptions);
                }
            },
            searchrules: { required: true }
        },
```

Parameters:

```
@section scripts{
<script>
   var paramFromView = {
        CurrencyOptions: {
            searchURL: '@Url.Action("GetCurrency", "Controller")',
            detailURL: '@Url.Action("CurrencyDetailsJson", "Controller")',
            idField: 'CurrencyID',
            txtField: 'Description'
        }
   };
</script>
}
```

Select2 Helper:

```
function intiGridFilterSelecr2Field(element, options) {
var comboPageSize = 15;
var quietMillis = 200;
var placeHolderText = 'Choose...'

var defaults = {
    searchURL: '',
    detailURL: '',
    idField: '',
    txtField: ''
};
var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
var select2Element = $(element);

select2Element.select2({
    width: 'element',
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    placeholder: placeHolderText,
    ajax: {
        url: options.searchURL,
        dataType: 'json',
        quietMillis: quietMillis,
        cache: false,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                name: params.term,
                page: params.page,
                pageSize: comboPageSize
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            var more = (data.page * comboPageSize) < data.total;

            var resultsArr = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++) {
                resultsArr.push({ id: data.result[i][options.idField], text: data.result[i][options.txtField] });
            }
            return { results: resultsArr, more: more };
        }
    },
}).each(function (index, element) {
    var idCombo = $(this);
     // The problem is that idCombo.val() is always empty.
     // element:select2-hidden-accessible
    if (idCombo.val() != null && idCombo.val().length > 0) {
        $.ajax(options.detailURL, {
            data: {
                id: idCombo.val()
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false
        }).done(function (data) {
            var optselected = select2Element.find('option').filter(function () { return this.value == data[idField] && this.text == data[txtField] && this.selected })
            if (optselected == undefined || optselected.length == 0) {
                var $optionContact = $("<option selected></option>").val(data[idField].toString()).text(data[txtField]);
                var toBeRemoved = select2Element.find('option').filter(function () { return this.value == data[idField] });
                if (toBeRemoved != undefined) {
                    toBeRemoved.remove();
                }
                select2Element.append($optionContact).trigger('change.select2');
            }
        });
    }

  });
}
```

When the filter is being set...
[image: When the filter is being set...]

When Loading the existing filter. How do I pass this CurrencyID = 1 to select2 helper?
[image: When Loading the existing filter]

**Update:**

With Oleg's answer, I updated my code as below.

```
            {
            name: 'CurrencyID', hidden: true, searchtype: 'number', search: true,
            stype: "select", searchoptions: {
                searchhidden: true,
                sopt: ["eq", "ne"],
                dataUrl: paramFromView.CurrencyOptions.searchURL,
                buildSelect: function (data) {
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    var i, options = [];
                    for (i = 0; i < obj.result.length; i++) {
                        options.push("<option value='" + obj.result[i][paramFromView.CurrencyOptions.idField] + "'>" +
                            obj.result[i][paramFromView.CurrencyOptions.txtField] + "</option>");
                    }
                    return "<select>" + options.join("") + "</select>";
                },
                noFilterText: "Any",
                selectFilled: function (options) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(options.elem).select2({
                            width: 'element',
                        });
                    }, 0);
                }
            },
            searchrules: { required: true }
        },
```

I'm almost there with what I wanted to achieve. However I'm still facing some difficulties.

1. When the filter is initially loaded, value is selected on the dropdown but query value is empty. i.e. if the user clicks on the find button soon after the filter form is loaded, no filter will be set.
2. I still cannot get select2 styles working.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can demonstrate how to use select2 with [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork of jqGrid, which I develop. I get the demo from the [README](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README4.14.1.md#new-main-features-implemented-in-the-version-4141-compared-with-4140) of the old version 4.14.1 (the current released version is 4.15.3) and modified it to demonstrate the usage of select2.

The main part of the code could be

```
stype: "select",
searchoptions: {
    sopt: ["eq", "ne"],
    ...
    selectFilled: function (options) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(options.elem).select2({
                width: "100%"
            });
        }, 0);
    }
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/Lae6kee7/2/. You can try to choose an option in the filter toolbar in "Shipped via" column and the open the search dialog. You will see that the select2 will have the same option selected.

If you would load the data via Ajax request posted by select2 than your code will be much more complex as it could be. It's important to understand that such way is really required only for really large set of possible value. I means the number of items larger as 100000 items for example. On the other side, the most use cases required less as 1000 options. In the case it would be more effective to load all the data as options of select and then convert the select to select2. select2, which uses local select works much more quickly from the users point of view.

The code will be easier in my opinion if you will use `dataUrl` instead of `ajax` option of `select2`. You can use `dataUrl` to return from the server all different values, which can be used in `select2` and to use `buildSelect` to build `<select>` from JSON data returned from the server. The demo https://jsfiddle.net/Lae6kee7/23/ demonstrates that. I made the demo for JSFiddle, which supports Echo service (see [here](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html#json)), which allows to simulate server responses. Your real code should contains mostly only `dataUrl`, `buildSelect` and the code of `selectFilled`, which I included above.

Additionally, I'd recommend you to consider to use `<datalist>` (see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp) for example), which could be good *alternative* to select2. All modern web browsers contains *native* support of `<datalist>` and thus `<datalist>` works very quickly. Try to search in the first `Client` column of my demos. You will see control, which will be very close to select2. Additional advantage of `<datalist>`: one will be able not search for only exact predefined values like `test10`, `test11` or `test12`, but for substrings like `1`. Compare

[image]

with

[image]

or

[image]

with

[image]

Comment: Hi Oleg, Thanks for all the work you have done with JqGrid. I think I'm almost there with your answer. two questions. Q1: I can only get select2 styles working with dataInit  but not with selectFilled. Q2: When the filter is initially loaded, even though value is set on the dropdown, query is null. any idea?

Comment: Please note that I'm referring to this: https://jsfiddle.net/Lae6kee7/23/  option.

Comment: @ecasper: You are welcome! Sorry, but I don't understand your current problem. Which version of jqGrid you used in your tests? What problem exists exactly in the demo https://jsfiddle.net/Lae6kee7/23/? Which steps one should do to reproduce the problem? What I do is 1) setting some filter in filter toolbar (for example, client contains "test", closed is false, Shipped via "TNT") 2) opening the searching dialog. I see the filter and the select2 contains TNT selected. One can do the same directly on load. See https://jsfiddle.net/Lae6kee7/29/. Just open Searching Dialog in the demo

Comment: I'm using select2 4.0.3 & JQgrid 4.6. Please see my updated code. first problem can be simulated in the demo jsfiddle.net/Lae6kee7/23. But I'm not sure why the select2 styles are not applying.

Comment: @ecasper: Sorry, but I started my answer, that I used the current version 4.15.3 of **free jqGrid** fork, which I develop. You wrote in your question about **min** 4.6 & Select2 **min** 4.0.1. jqGrid 4.6 is dead, it's more as 4 years old. Free jjqGrid is compatible with jqGrid 4.6, but I rewrite many ports of the source code and made many changes in jqGrid CSS.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have just updated it to 4.15.3 and select2 styles are back. Thanks a lot! Do you have a suggestion for the first problem. i.e. query value is being null with initial loading?

Comment: May be add dummy place holder? options.push("<option value=-1>Choose...</option>");

Comment: @ecasper: Could you provide **the demo**, which can be used to reproduce your current problem? I suppose that the problem exist in the for, in which you use select2. **How many items totally you can have in `CurrencyID` column?** Just from the name I can suppose that you should have less as 200 items (164 official national currencies circulating around the world). In the case, one could return *all items at once* from `dataUrl` and the usage of `select2` could be reduced to one line. The user will get the response from select2 practically immediately if all data are loaded locally. Is it so?